# Unity - Polygon Collider 2D no sigue a mi personaje

Tags: unity2d

Estoy practicando con *unity*, y estaba siguiendo un tutorial que explicaba paso por paso el como desarrollar un simple juego plataformero.

El problema que tengo es que, al designarle un Polygon Collider 2D a mi personaje, este no lo sigue al momento de realizar un salto, provocando que en todo momento pierda el juego. El trigger funciona perfectamente.

No estoy utilizando las propiedades de gravedad de *unity*, el salto es enteramente una animacion.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en la ventana de animacion, puedes modificar el collider de la animacion, asi seguira a tu personaje

Comment: Si el salto es una animación pura y dura, no hay ningún error en el Polygon Collider 2D porque el personaje no salta realmente. En ningún momento le estas diciendo al personaje que cambie su posición. Tienes dos opciones, haces lo que te recomienda Zhet (comentario de arriba) o programas el salto por código sin usar las físicas de Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes modificar el collider durante la animacion, asi solo afectara a la animacion, te dejo un gif para que veas como quedaria
[link del gif](https://gph.is/2Olmzhd)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio lo que me publicaste, ahora podre seguir perfectamente con el juego.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es modificar la Y del objeto jugador, el collider debería ser hijo del jugador, por lo que heredará los cambios de posición del padre.

Asegúrate que en la animación que estás montando no quede espacio en blanco por la parte de abajo, por lo que estas mostrando no modificas la Y, simplemente ejecutas el cambio de la animación dando la sensación de que está saltando pero en realidad el objeto jugador no se mueve.